# Javascript change drop-down box options based on another drop-down box value

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

I am practising programming in JavaScript and I have found a problem that must be answered by some experts regarding `drop-down` boxes.

The Scenario is:

I have a `drop-down` box that gives some possible options for provinces and also a second one (town) which depends only on what is selected in the provinces `drop-down`.

Is there a way in JavaScript that when I chose among provinces, the second `drop-down` gives the options from the province selected?

Comment: Have you tired anything?

Comment: I think "must be answered by experts" is a bit strong, google could have probably got you there

Comment: Yo can find the answer here allready:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686735/populate-one-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another  Alltrough, i would use Jquery for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you started.

It works by attaching an event listener for the `change` event to the province dropdown, then looks up what towns are in that province via the `provs` object.

See the comments for a detailed explanation of what each line does.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // provs is an object but you can think of it as a lookup table
  var provs = {
        'British Columbia': ['Victoria', 'Sanitch'],
        'Ontario': ['Bracebridge', 'Waterloo']
      },
      // just grab references to the two drop-downs
      prov_select = document.querySelector('#prov'),
      town_select = document.querySelector('#town');

  // populate the provinces drop-down
  setOptions(prov_select, Object.keys(provs));
  // populate the town drop-down
  setOptions(town_select, provs[prov_select.value]);
  
  // attach a change event listener to the provinces drop-down
  prov_select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // get the towns in the selected province
    setOptions(town_select, provs[prov_select.value]);
  });
    
  function setOptions(dropDown, options) {
    // clear out any existing values
    dropDown.innerHTML = '';
    // insert the new options into the drop-down
    options.forEach(function(value) {
      dropDown.innerHTML += '<option name="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
    });
  }  
};
```

```html
<select id="prov"></select>
<select id="town"></select>
```