# bootstrap multiselect dropdown change values based on other multiselect

Tags: javascript

I want to use the multiselect dropdown of bootstrap to change the values based on other multiselect, what I have right now only works with one seleccion, but when I add the `class="selectpicker"` it stops working and also I lost my options.

this is the code I´m using:

html:

```
<select id="deptos" class="selectpicker"></select>
<select id="munis" class="selectpicker"></select>
```

javascript:
the original script comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802104/javascript-change-drop-down-box-options-based-on-another-drop-down-box-value)

```
<script>    
window.onload = function() {
        var depto = JSON.parse("{{deptos|escapejs}}"),//deptos comes from a django view.
            depto_select = document.querySelector('#deptos'),
            muni_select = document.querySelector('#munis');

        setOptions(depto_select, Object.keys(depto));
        setOptions(muni_select, depto[depto_select.value]);
        
        depto_select.addEventListener('change', function() {
            setOptions(muni_select, depto[depto_select.value]);
        });
            
        function setOptions(dropDown, options) {
            dropDown.innerHTML = '';
            options.forEach(function(value) {
            dropDown.innerHTML += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
        }  
    };

    $('select').selectpicker();
</script>
```

this is how it works with simple selections:

[image]

[image]

but when I add the `class="selectpicker"` it becomes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to had `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')` in setOptions() methods:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // provs is an object but you can think of it as a lookup table
  var provs = {
        'British Columbia': ['Victoria', 'Sanitch'],
        'Ontario': ['Bracebridge', 'Waterloo']
      },
      // just grab references to the two drop-downs
      prov_select = document.querySelector('#prov'),
      town_select = document.querySelector('#town');

  // populate the provinces drop-down
  setOptions(prov_select, Object.keys(provs));
  // populate the town drop-down
  setOptions(town_select, provs[prov_select.value]);
  
  // attach a change event listener to the provinces drop-down
  prov_select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // get the towns in the selected province
    setOptions(town_select, provs[prov_select.value]);
  });
    
  function setOptions(dropDown, options) {
    // clear out any existing values
    dropDown.innerHTML = '';
    // insert the new options into the drop-down
    options.forEach(function(value) {
      dropDown.innerHTML += '<option>' + value + '</option>';
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') //I add this line from previous version
  }  
};
```

```html
<html>

<!-- I imported it because I don't download it XD -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<select id="prov" class="selectpicker"></select>
<select id="town" class="selectpicker"></select> <!--You can add multiple after class="" to have multiple selection-->

</html>
```

Comment: I haven´t change anything in the selectpicker class, Im just using the custom bootstrap class

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I had misunderstood. I've found a solution, look at the edit and keep me informed.

Comment: It works, the only thing is that it only works for simple selections, no multi

Comment: You can just apply `multiple` to `<select id="town" class="selectpicker" multiple></select>` but not to `<select id="prov" class="selectpicker"></select>`